# How can I align justify between like justify-start for uneven items at the end in css (tailwind)?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, tailwind-css

How can I achieve this (this uses grid) with flexbox `justify-between`? [image: grid]

In flexbox `justify-between`, the result would be like this. I tried justify-start and gave it `mx-auto`, but it would be like `justify-center`, and the result would not be the same as grid row
[image: flexbox]

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is almost impossible thing to do using only flexbox since flexbox is one-dimensional layout model.

## Solution

The only solution that came to my mind how to solve this using flexbox is add `grow` class to the last element, that will cause the last element will take all empty space on last row

```html
<div class="flex justify-between flex-wrap">
    <div class="last:grow">
      ...
    </div>
</div>
```

But be aware that behavior of this solution is similar to `mx-auto` or `mr-auto`: the last row with uneven elements will ignore spacing between columns (elements)

## Recommendation

I would highly recommend you to use grid layout, because grid is two-dimensional layout model, so you can prevent "unexpected"/unwanted behavior on some viewports.

Hope this helped you.

Comment: yeah, I tried it and it gave unwanted behavior immediately. Maybe I should use grid. What I don't like with grid is, it's somehow will intersect, like colliding, to each element in certain pixel in medium viewport. Maybe I'm to overanalyze/overcomplicate something?

Comment: There should not be any problem with anything like that. The problem may be changing margin of elements or hardcoding width.